# Count the frequency of a df in percent

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

So I have a pandas dataframe

```
d = {'col1': [1, 2, 1, 6, 6, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2]}
dataframe = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

It is a quite large dataframe. What is the best way to output the frequency in percentage with **print-statement**?

For example:

```
1: 40 %
2: 40 %
6: 20 %
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`Series.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) with `normalize=True`:

```
print (dataframe['col1'].value_counts(normalize=True).mul(100))
1    40.0
2    40.0
6    20.0
Name: col1, dtype: float64
```

---

```
print (dataframe['col1'].value_counts(normalize=True).mul(100).map("{:,.0f} %".format))
1    40 %
2    40 %
6    20 %
Name: col1, dtype: object
```

Like mentioned @Ch3steR is possible simplify solution with omit multiple by `100` and format:

```
print (dataframe['col1'].value_counts(normalize=True).map("{:.2%}".format))

1    40.00%
2    40.00%
6    20.00%
Name: col1, dtype: object
```

Comment: You can actually avoid `.mul(100)` if you use `"{:.0%}".format` it does that operation itself. Example, `"{:.2%}".format(0.1) ` -> `10.00%`, where `.2` is for precision.